# Rails help with select and render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Want to create a select that tells what info to pass to the partial in a Rails 3 App.

Currently.
Lets say default is

```
<% orders_date_range = @orders.closed_today %>
```

Then

```
<div id="reports">
  <%= render :partial => "report_details", :locals => { :orders => orders_date_range } %>
</div>
```

Can I create a select tag to pass in the orders_date_range?  Or is there a better way of doing this?

---

UPDATE

```
<% orders = @orders.closed_today %>
<% @options = [["this week", @orders.closed_this_week],["this year", @orders.closed_this_year]]%>
<%= select 'orders', 'order', @options.collect {|f| [f[0], f[1]]}, :remote => true %>


<div id="reports">
   <%= render :partial => "report_details", :locals => { :orders => orders } %>
</div>
```

Don't know why, but would only work with 'orders', 'order' for select.

applicaton.js

```
$("#orders_order").change(function(){
  $.getScript("reports");
});
```

reports.js.erb

```
$("#reports").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'report_details', :locals => { :orders => params[:selected] } ) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably would be cool to do this as an AJAX thing....

**Form.erb:**

```
#call this at the top of your view
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

<%= select 'orders', 'option', @options.collect {|f| [f[0], f[1]]}, :onchange => remote_function(:url => {:action => :render_my_partial}, :with => 'Form.Element.Serialize(this)' %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def form
    @options = [["option1", option1],["option2", option2]...] 
end 

def render_my_partial
  render update do |page|
    page.replace_html 'reports', :partial => 'report_details', :orders => params[:orders][:option] 
  end
end
```

Comment: trying to fill in the blank with your ..., but its not firing.  added method and added to routes.  Did `select "params", "orders", [["this week", @orders.closed_this_week], ["this month", @orders.closed_this_month]], :onchange` but not working.

Comment: Updated with something a little more thorough

Comment: using jquery, not prototype.  thought could figure the conversion my self, but can't.